# Python add an excel file sheet into an other excel file as a new sheet without changing formats

Tags: python, excel, dataframe, openpyxl

I have 2 excel files: file1 and file2, I want to add sheets of file2 into file1 without changing the format of the sheets (cell colors, font size, merged cells etc...)

I tried to execute the below code, but I lost all formats of file2's sheet:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.utils.dataframe import dataframe_to_rows


# Load both Excel files
file1_path = 'path/to/file1.xlsx'
file2_path = 'path/to/file2.xlsx'

wb1 = load_workbook(file1_path)
wb2 = load_workbook(file2_path)

# Get the first sheet of file2
sheet2 = wb2.worksheets[0]

# Create a new sheet in file1
new_sheet = wb1.create_sheet(title='Appended_Sheet')

# Copy values and formatting from sheet2 to the new sheet
for row in dataframe_to_rows(sheet2, index=False, header=True):
    new_sheet.append(row)

# Save the updated file1
  wb1.save('path/to/updated_file1.xlsx')
```

Any idea could help, thanks

Comment: Why are you using `dataframe_to_rows()`? This will fail in this context. If you are trying to copy cells from one workbook to another with their styling then search for this because it's been asked many times,